# New custom loss function gives me error Error: Expected int64, but got 0.9999999 of type 'float'

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras, loss

I wanted to customize my loss function. I've started with this one:

```
from keras import backend as K
def loss2( y_true, y_pred, weight=1. ) :
    y_true = K.clip(y_true, K.epsilon(), 1-K.epsilon())
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1-K.epsilon())
    logloss = -(y_true * K.log(y_pred) * weight + (1 - y_true) * K.log(1 - y_pred))
    return float(K.mean( logloss, axis=-1))
```

The model I'm going to train is:

```
def build_model(l1,l2,l3,batch_size, epochs, optimizer,d1,d2,d3):#l1,l2,l3,batch_size, epochs, optimizer,d1,d2,d3):
  modelfnntuning = Sequential()
  modelfnntuning.add(Dense(l1, input_shape=(X_trainfnn.shape[1], ), activation='relu',kernel_initializer="glorot_normal"))
  modelfnntuning.add(Dropout(d1))
  modelfnntuning.add(Dense(l2, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="glorot_normal"))
  modelfnntuning.add(Dropout(d2))
  modelfnntuning.add(Dense(l3, activation='relu',kernel_initializer="glorot_normal"))
  modelfnntuning.add(Dropout(d3))
modelfnntuning.add(Dense(len(dataframe[dataframe.columns.values[dataframe.shape[1]-1]].unique().tolist()), activation='softmax'))
modelfnntuning.compile(loss=loss2, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['binary_accuracy','categorical_accuracy','Recall','AUC'])
  return modelfnntuning
```

And as you can see in the .compile I have put the new loss function defined (loss2):

The error is given at the gridsearch point:

```
grid_search.fit(X = X, y = y)
```

The error is:

> Expected int64 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Minimum', got 0.9999999
> of type 'float' instead. Error: Expected int64, but got 0.9999999 of
> type 'float'.

I have tried to change the types to the input data. But I'm wrong. The model is tested without changing the loss function and works perfectly.

Comment: Please add appropriate tags for the language and library you're using